# Python API documentation for FAISS

Tags: python, nlp, faiss, similarity-search

I am searching for a Python API documentation for FAISS, unable to find it. The wiki page says the python translation is very close to the C++ classes whose documentation can be found [here](https://faiss.ai/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Python version of Faiss contains just wrappers to the C++ functions (generated with [Swig](https://github.com/swig/swig)), so the Python functions match the C++ ones. From [their wiki](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki#this-wiki):

> Most examples are in Python for brievity, but the C++ API is exactly the same, so the translation for one to the other is trivial most of the times.

You can use their ["getting stated" page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Getting-started), which contains Python examples, as well as their ["Python-C++ code-snippets" page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Python-C---code-snippets), which contains links to jupyter notebooks with sample Python code.